# Error: StaticInjectorError[FormBuilder] when running ng test

Tags: angular

I have just started using `ng test` to verify my Angular app. I used Angular-Cli to generate my modules and components and the .spec.ts were straight out of the box.

I am getting the following on one test:

> Error: StaticInjectorError[FormBuilder]:
>   StaticInjectorError[FormBuilder]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for FormBuilder!

The component it fails on has these declared

```
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
```

And my constructor just news up a FormBuilder

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
```

I also have the form builder declared in my app.module

```
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AdminModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormBuilder,
    HttpModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot()
```

Test code

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { CreatearchiveComponent } from './createarchive.component';
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

describe('CreatearchiveComponent', () => {
  let component: CreatearchiveComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CreatearchiveComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ CreatearchiveComponent ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CreatearchiveComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Your app module is irrelevant. What matters is the test module configured in your test.

Comment: Can you please provide your test? I think you just forgot to add the `ReactiveFormsModule` to your testing module configuration

Comment: for future reference: avoid using the NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA unless you really need it, the best solution being to isolate your component by stubbing the references. See the docu: https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#no_errors_schema

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your test uses a testing angular module which only has a `CreatearchiveComponent`, but doesn't import ReactiveFormsModule. So the FormBuilder service, provided by ReactiveFormsModule, is not available. You need to import the modules that are needed by the component under test:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ CreatearchiveComponent ],
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not create formgroup instant in constructor body. Please create formgroup instant at top of the component class and use the same in your code.

Comment: I am interested to know why you shouldn't do this?

Comment: I think there is a little bit of a mixup here.
The problem that the OP is having is related to FormBUILDER, which needs to be injected in the constructor.
This answer mentions FormGROUP, which needs to be instantiated (with "new"). You can see that in the docu: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#creating-nested-form-groups


I'm a bit surprised that the OP imported both of them, but maybe he needed them. From a testing point of view, afaik they are both not easy to isolate. Hence importing "ReactiveFormsModule" does the trick.